# Discord bot command not working returning error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to start learning how to code a Discord bot.
But when I run the code and say the command "!hello"
it just says this error message:

Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
Process exited with code 1

How do I fix it?

```
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Client();

const token = new String("")

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log("I am online!");
})

bot.on('message', (message) =>{

    console.log("HELLO");
    
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    let prefix = '!';
    let MessageArray = message.content.split(' ');

    let cmd = MessageArray[0].slice(prefix.length);
    let args = MessageArray.slice(1);

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    //command

    if(cmd === hello){
        console.log("command sent");
        message.channel.send("Hello there!");
    }
})

bot.login(token censored)
```

Comment: Missing quotes, it should be `cmd === 'hello'`. There is no `hello` variable.

Comment: i realized that i forgot the top part. I put "const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js")" already

Answer (score 2):

Within your code, you have

```
if(cmd === hello){
```

However, hello is not a variable that you have defined in your code, hence the error stating that you don't have it defined, instead, it should be placed into quotation marks to express that it should compare cmd to "hello" (a string).

For example:

```
if(cmd === "hello"){
```